# Pydev, eclipse, pauses when I press . in interactive mode

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse, when in interactive mode, when I type in a variable name and press ., so that the list of hints pops up, there is a big pause.

How can I prevent the big pause?

Comment: Define "big", please

Answer (score 1):

When you press '.' it'll get the code-completion for the variable you have... probably getting those variables is slow in your use case (because of some construct in your own code).

Mostly PyDev will do a dir(obj) and getattr(obj, attr_name)... So, if inspecting your object is slow, that'll be slow too.

To improve that you can disable the auto code completion on '.' or you can make your object more friendly to inspections.